# In case of redundant optimization flags, which one gets implemented?

Tags: gfortran

I have the following gfortran compilation.  Which one of the optimization flags (`-O` or `-O2`)
will actually get implemented by gfortran?  I tried doing an octal dump of the resultant
object file, but did not have any luck.  Thank you!

```
gfortran -c -O -Wuninitialized -fno-automatic -fno-range-check -ffixed-line-length-none -O2 -I. goes_imgr_sky_cvr_ji.f
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the documentation correctly, each `-O` level switches on a set of optimization flags. Since higher levels include all options of the levels below it, the highest level on the command line defines the full set of flags enabled.
You can interpret it as if the flags of the lower levels just get switched on twice (and it doesn't work as a double negative, so setting them twice doesn't turn them off again).

You can check for yourself, though, because, going through [the documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options), I came across the following invocation, which will list the optimizations enabled and disabled.

```
gfortran -Q --help=optimizers <rest of your command line>
```